# Firebird CASE statement inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, case, firebird, control-flow

I was trying to use the `case` statement inside a stored procedure but I got "Token unknown" on it. `case` is not supported in stored procedure? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CASE statement only within SELECT operator. Standalone usage is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

As Andrei wrote, `CASE` is only available in `SELECT` statements. So the trick to use it is to select from some table which has only one row, like `RDB$DATABASE`:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    ...
  END
FROM RDB$DATABASE INTO :myVAR;
```

Of course, this is only usefull in case you want to assign value to a variable based on some conditions, if you need a control flow statement then `IF / ELSE` ladder is the only option.